# How to validate a user name with regex?

Tags: regex

This seems to match the rules I have defined, but I only starting learning regex tonight, so I am wondering if it is correct.

Rules:

- Usernames can consist of lowercase
  and capitals
- Usernames can consist of alphanumeric
  characters
- Usernames can consist of underscore
  and hyphens and spaces
- Cannot be two underscores, two hypens
  or two spaces in a row
- Cannot have a underscore, hypen or
  space at the start or end

Regex pattern:

```
/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+([a-zA-Z0-9](_|-| )[a-zA-Z0-9])*[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/
```

Comment: This won't allow any non-Latin characters in usernames. If you want to be able to handle non-Latin characters you should use a built-in character class instead of explicitly defining which characters are letters and numbers.

Comment: You can test your expression online:
http://www.gskinner.com/RegExr/

Comment: `/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+([a-zA-Z0-9](_|-| )[a-zA-Z0-9])*[a-zA-Z0-9]*$/` is enough. No need to add `+` at the last

Comment: I actually provided an answer to [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/435120/284004). The patterns provided are not fully accurate and can be simplified greatly.

Comment: This will give you a good idea: https://ihateregex.io/expr/username

Answer (score 83, accepted):

The specs in the question aren't very clear, so I'll just assume the string can contain only ASCII letters and digits, with hyphens, underscores and spaces as internal separators.  The meat of the problem is insuring that the first and last character are not separators, and that there's never more than one separator in a row (that part seems clear, anyway).  Here's the simplest way:

```
/^[A-Za-z0-9]+(?:[ _-][A-Za-z0-9]+)*$/
```

After matching one or more alphanumeric characters, *if* there's a separator it *must* be followed by one or more alphanumerics; repeat as needed.

Let's look at regexes from some of the other answers.

```
/^[[:alnum:]]+(?:[-_ ]?[[:alnum:]]+)*$/
```

This is effectively the same (assuming your regex flavor supports the POSIX character-class notation), but why make the separator optional?  The only reason you'd be in that part of the regex in the first place is if there's a separator or some other, invalid character.

```
/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+([_\s\-]?[a-zA-Z0-9])*$/
```

On the other hand, this only works *because* the separator is optional.  After the first separator, it can only match one alphanumeric at a time.  To match more, it has to keep repeating the whole group: zero separators followed by one alphanumeric, over and over.  If the second `[a-zA-Z0-9]` were followed by a plus sign, it could find a match by a much more direct route.

```
/^[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9_\s\-]*[a-zA-Z0-9](?<![_\s\-]{2,}.*)$/
```

This uses unbounded lookbehind, which is a very rare feature, but you can use a lookahead to the same effect:

```
/^(?!.*[_\s-]{2,})[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9_\s\-]*[a-zA-Z0-9]$/
```

This performs essentially a separate search for two consecutive separators, and fails the match if it finds one.  The main body then only needs to make sure all the characters are alphanumerics or separators, with the first and last being alphanumerics.  Since those two are required, the name must be at least two characters long.

```
/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+([a-zA-Z0-9](_|-| )[a-zA-Z0-9])*[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/
```

This is your own regex, and it requires the string to start and end with two alphanumeric characters, and if there are two separators within the string, there have to be exactly two alphanumerics between them.  So `ab`, `ab-cd` and `ab-cd-ef` will match, but `a`, `a-b` and `a-b-c` won't.

Also, as some of the commenters have pointed out, the `(_|-| )` in your regex should be `[-_ ]`.  That part's not *incorrect*, but if you have a choice between an alternation and a character class, you should always go with the character class: they're more efficient as well as more readable.

Again, I'm not worried about whether "alphanumeric" is supposed to include non-ASCII characters, or the exact meaning of "space", just how to enforce a policy of non-contiguous internal separators with a regex.

Comment: ok, and how to limit this? something like:
     ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+([a-zA-Z0-9](_|-| )[a-zA-Z0-9])*[a-zA-Z0-9]+){6,25}$

Comment: @GabrielAnderson: You mean the whole name (including separators) must be at least 6 and at most 25 characters long?  That requires a lookahead.  Just add `(?=.{6,25}$)` to the beginning, right after the anchor (`^`).

Answer (score 32):

You regular expression can be simplified to:

```
/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+([_ -]?[a-zA-Z0-9])*$/
```

Visualized with [Regexper](https://regexper.com/#%5E%5Ba-zA-Z0-9%5D%2B(%3F%3A%5B_%20-%5D%3F%5Ba-zA-Z0-9%5D)*%24):

[image: Visualization of username validation regex.]

As you can see a user name always has to start with an alphanumeric character. Special characters (`_`, , `-`) have to be followed by an alphanumeric character. The last character has to be an alphanumeric character.

Comment: important tool for [regex] (https://regexper.com/#%5E%5Ba-zA-Z%5D%2B%28%3F%3A%5B_-%5D%3F%5Ba-zA-Z%5D%29*%24)

Answer (score 7):

```
 ([a-zA-Z0-9](_|-| )[a-zA-Z0-9])*
```

is a 0 or more repetiton of alphanum, dashspace, alphanum.

So it would match

```
a_aa_aa_a
```

but not

```
aaaaa
```

The complete regexp can't match

```
a_aaaaaaaaa_a for example.
```

Let's look back at what you want:

```
* Usernames can consist of lowercase and capitals or alphanumerica characters
* Usernames can consist of alphanumeric characters
* Usernames can consist of underscore and hyphens and spaces
* Cannot be two underscores, two hypens or two spaces in a row
* Cannot have a underscore, hypen or space at the start or end
```

The beginning is simple ... just match an alphanum, then (ingoring the two in the row rule) an (alphanum or dashspace)* and at the and an alphanum again.

To prevent the two dashspaces in a row you probably need to understand lookahead/lookbehind.

Oh, and regarding the other answer: Please download Espresso, it REALLY helps you undestand those things.

Comment: Show a man how to fish by catching a fish yourself to prove that your methods work?

Answer (score 3):

I suggest writing some unit tests to put the Regex through it's paces.  This will also help a few months from now when you find a problem with the Regex and need to update it.

Comment: +1. It's definitely a good idea to cover regex's with several unit tests

Answer (score 3):

1. Alphanumerical isn't just `[a-zA-Z0-9]`, it's accented, Cyrillic, Greek and other letters, which can be used in username.
2. `(_|-| )` can be replaced by `[-_ ]` character class

Comment: `[_- ]` is "everything between underscore and space". You want to have the hyphen first to have it interpreted properly: `[-_ ]`

Answer (score 1):

By the looks of it, that rule wouldn't match something like "a_bc", "ab_c", "a_b" or "a_b_c".

Try: `/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+([_\s\-]?[a-zA-Z0-9])*$/`
which matches the above cases but not any combination of spaces, dashes or underscores next to each other. Eg: "_-" or " _" are not allowed.

Answer (score 1):

Using the POSIX character class for alphanumeric characters to make it work for accented and other foreign alphabetic characters:

```
/^[[:alnum:]]+([-_ ]?[[:alnum:]])*$/
```

More efficient (prevents captures):

```
/^[[:alnum:]]+(?:[-_ ]?[[:alnum:]]+)*$/
```

These also prevent sequences of more than one space/hyphen/underscore in combination.
It doesn't follow from your specification whether that is desirable, but your own regex
seems to indicate this is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Another recommendation for [Expresso 3.0](http://www.ultrapico.com/Expresso.htm) here - very easy to use and build up strings with.

Answer (score 0):

Your regex doesn't work. The hard part is the check for consecutive spaces/hyphens. You could use this one, which uses look-behind:

```
/^[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9_\s\-]*[a-zA-Z0-9](?<![_\s\-]{2,}.*)$/
```

Comment: This won't work in the majority of regexp engines because the look-behind string is not fixed length.

Comment: I'm spoiled by the .NET regex engine :)

Comment: Yeah, I meant to mention in my comment that the .NET engine is one of a handful where it *will* work :-)

Comment: Some engines are ok with a limited-length, rather than fixed-length. e.g. just use `.{0,999}` instead of `.*`

Comment: (For a username, you can probably get away with {0,99} or even lower.)

Comment: The `{0,n}` trick would work in Java, but most regex flavors require a fixed-length expression, if they support lookbehinds at all.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, adding a limited scope to this model would be better

[a-zA-Z0-9]+([_ -]?[a-zA-Z0-9]){5,40}$

[image]