# Writing a Regular Expression for not including something

Tags: regex, regex-negation

How can I write a Regular Expression to match,

```
    a string which does not contain the underscore "_".
```

Comment: I actually meant this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1873436

Answer (score 9, accepted):

/^[^_]*$/

The [^] syntax means "do not include any of these characters".

Comment: That was simple. What was I thinking? Actually this was a simplification of a large regular expression problem, whose partial answer I found here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1240674/
I guess I over simplified it while trying to isolate the problem. And couldn't find this simple answer in the mess. Anyway, thanks for enlightening.

Answer (score 0):

To match a character that is not an underscore you'd use `[^_]` (the `^` means "not"). So to match a whole string you'd do something like this:

```
/[^_]+/
```

Comment: It would match the "a" in "a_", yes.