# Regular expression for not matching two underscores

Tags: ruby, regex

I don't know whether it's really easy and I'm out of my mind....

In Ruby's regular expressions, how to match strings which do not contain two consecutive underscores, i.e., "__".

Ex:

```
Matches: "abcd", "ab_cd", "a_b_cd", "%*##_@+"
Does not match: "ab__cd", "a_b__cd"
```

-thanks

EDIT: I can't use reverse logic, i.e., checking for "__" strings and excluding them, since need to use with Ruby on Rails "validates_format_of()" which expects a regular expression with which it will *match*.

Comment: I think that this is a design mistake in `validates_format_of`.  It should take a general predicate.  Regular expressions are an implementation detail.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
/^([^_]*(_[^_])?)*_?$/
```

Tests:

```
regex=/^([^_]*(_[^_])?)*_?$/

# Matches    
puts "abcd" =~ regex
puts "ab_cd" =~ regex
puts "a_b_cd" =~ regex
puts "%*##_@+" =~ regex
puts "_" =~ regex
puts "_a_" =~ regex

# Non-matches
puts "__" =~ regex
puts "ab__cd" =~ regex
puts "a_b__cd" =~ regex
```

But regex is overkill for this task. A simple string test is much easier:

```
puts ('a_b'['__'])
```

Comment: Works great, and looks so "not-complex" (comparatively). Also, thanks for taking time for writing those examples. I just had to do a "copy-paste" to my `irb` session for validations. Also, another right answer - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1873436/regular-expression-for-not-matching-two-underscores/1873474#1873474

Answer (score 12):

You could use negative lookahead:

```
^((?!__).)*$
```

The beginning-of-string `^` and end of string `$` are important, they force a check of "not followed by double underscore" on every position.

Comment: In Ruby `^` and `$` are beginning-of-line and end-of-line respectively (for strings that contain multiple lines). Strictly, use `\A` and `\Z` for beginning-of-string and end-of-string

Comment: Thanks, works great. But, unfortunately I can select only one answer, so chosen "Mark Byers", as his solution is, well, simple. Nonetheless, +1 for sure.

Comment: Yesterday, I didn't select your answer as accepted one, because then I didn't know about the "negative lookahead" thing, but now I do. And so, now I find your answer like, "wow". I tried to modify it, but can't get any better.
Thanks for answering.

Answer (score 2):

Would altering your logic still be valid?

You could check if the string contains two underscores with the regular expression [_]{2} and then just ignore it?

Answer (score 0):

Negative lookahead

```
\b(?!\w*__\w*)\w+\b
```

Search for two consecutive underscores in the next word from the beginning of the word, and match that word if it is not found.

Edit: To accommodate anything other than whitespaces in the match:

```
(?!\S*__\S*)\S+
```

If you wish to accommodate a subset of symbols, you can write something like the following, but then it will match `_cd` from `a_b__cd` among other things.

```
(?![a-zA-Z0-9_%*#@+]*__[a-zA-Z0-9_%*#@+]*)[a-zA-Z0-9_%*#@+]+
```

Comment: @Gumbo: \w stands for "word character", usually [A-Za-z0-9_]. Notice the inclusion of the underscore and digits

Comment: Fixed to search for `__` anywhere in the next word

Comment: Ah, sorry. Mixed it up with `-`.

Comment: what are the possible characters? replace `\w` with something like `[a-zA-Z0-9%*#_@+]` to match the required characters.

Comment: Got the concept. But, @Andomar has a better pattern for negative lookahead (talking by length). Still, will give a +1. Many thanks for stopping by and answering

Comment: @Andomar's regex assumes that you are passing only the test string. I was trying to find matches in a given string. Test the following string with both regexes (with global flag on) and see the outputs: ` "abcd", "ab_cd", "a_b_cd", "%*##_@+"  "ab__cd", "a_b__cd"`

Comment: I'm really sorry, but I fail to see the point. Both work well for me. With only the difference that for string "%*##_@+", @Andomar's pattern matches at 0 and yours at 4th.
Also, I didn't get the global flag thing.