# how to restrict numbers in regex

Tags: c#, regex

**i have a regex
^[a-zA-Z0-9]{0,14}$** 
which will allow only alphanumerics.
but there is problem i dont want a username to be only numbers and this regex is accepting only numbers also
like 56426542
**so how to restrict only numbers**

Comment: I believe this will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1221985/how-to-validate-a-user-name-with-regex

Comment: the problem is white spaces should not be there. it is not good to have white spaces.how to avoid that?

Comment: Do you have to do it with a single regex? Writing a few lines more can make your code more readable.

Comment: You probably don't want {0,14} - I would think a user name needs to be at least one character long.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The regex you want:

```
^((?=.*[a-zA-Z])[a-zA-Z0-9]{0,14})$
```

[Regex sandbox to play in with it.](http://regexpal.com/?flags=gm&regex=%5E%28%28%3F%3D.%2a%5Ba-zA-Z%5D%29%5Ba-zA-Z0-9%5D%7B0%2C14%7D%29%24&input=a8dyh22312dc78%0A12345678901234%0Aabcdefg-ijklmn%0A1234567890123a%0Aabcdefghijklm1%0A1234567890123as%0A1234567890123a)

This won't force you to have to start with a letter.  The username can start with a letter or a number, an ensures that the username isn't *only* numbers.

Edit: fixed the length check.  Also, you might want to change the {0,14} to {1,14}.  Well, replace the first number with your minimum length requirement.

Comment: The only problem with this is that it no longer restricts the length to 14 chars

Comment: No problem!  I actually used one of the sample patterns from this Regex Cheat Sheet: http://www.addedbytes.com/cheat-sheets/regular-expressions-cheat-sheet/.  The Password strength one.  Great resource, at least for me.

Answer (score 1):

TIMTOWTDI

The simpliest solution is to require a username to start with a letter

`^[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9]{0,14}`

Keep in mind that {0,14} accepts empty string as a valid input

**Edit**
The previous expression accepts 1 to 15 characters of input a little better solution is:`^[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9]{0,13}`

But Grommer solution is better