# how to validate user name field by entering special charater in it (It should allow the special character)

Tags: javascript

I want to validate user name input field by entering special characters:

```
!`@#$%^&*()+=-[]\\\';,./{}|\":<>?~_
```

here is my code:

```
function specialcharecter()
{
    var iChars = "!`@#$%^&*()+=-[]\\\';,./{}|\":<>?~_";   
    var data = document.getElementById("txtCallSign").value;
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
    {      
        if (iChars.indexOf(data.charAt(i)) != -1)
        {    
            alert ("Your string has special characters. \nThese are not allowed.");
            document.getElementById("txtCallSign").value = "";
            return false; 
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: Please look at the preview before submitting a question. If necessary check the link towards the help that you find in the edit toolbar.

Comment: What's the problem with your code ?

Comment: @Manu Yes. Whats wrong with your code?

Comment: Best way would be to go for regEx checking for alphabets and numbers. What if the user enters any other special characters

Comment: my requiremnt is if if the user enters any other special characters – It should allow him to enter..

Comment: As for me - better is to use 'white list' instead of 'black list'. Only in this way you'll be sure that no additional/unexpected chars will be used/saved in DB. E.g. [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1221985/how-to-validate-a-user-name-with-regex) you can check for example regexp.